# Is there a way to name a dog without using voice?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

Today in Nintendogs + Cats: Toy Poodle & New Friends I got a new puppy and it keeps telling me to use my voice to name her but I can't use my voice or make any noise.

Is there anyway I can skip the record voice part and name the dog without using voice?

Comment: It may help generate solutions if you can explain why you can't use your voice or make any noise.

Comment: You can't *ever* use your voice or make any noise?  Like, ever, your entire life?  Assuming the reason you can't make any noise is just temporary (for example, it's the middle of the night and you're supposed to be sleeping) then perhaps you should consider putting this game away until you *can make noise,* and play something else instead (or, you know, go to sleep.)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

You **cannot** name your dog without using your voice/a microphone. Voice is also an important part in the game as it is constantly used to call your pet and perform other actions within the game.

Answer (score 1):

While I've never played the game, I don't think it has any excessive built in voice recognition and instead uses that one recorded sample to later on detect you calling the pet.

As such I'd assume you can pretty much use any audible signal you can think of as a replacement. I might be wrong, but have you tried anything else, like a bell, clicker, etc.?

Comment: A fair portion of the game revolves around how you pronounce your pet's name and how oftenly you do so. If you pronounce it differently multiple times then the pet will become confused, too scarcely and it will forget it's own name.